# c# Component Executing Life Cycle

Tags: c#, components, lifecycle

I created a component in my solution. I can use this component on my form.
I did operation like this:

1. I created a Class Library ,created my component..
2. create a test project and add referances in my soloution  my component in test project.

I have some code for what my components do. I write a function for this but i dont know how i use my function in my component. I need the help for this. I want to learn my components work which project ? so, i need to call my function when components after loading on my form. Because i need to learn project name this form.
Here is my component

```
[System.ComponentModel.Description("This component using for update an application")] 
public class MyComponent : System.Windows.Forms.Control
{
    protected static string userName;
    protected static string userPassWord;
    ButtonState state = ButtonState.Normal;



    [System.ComponentModel.Description("UserName for DB Connection"), 
    System.ComponentModel.Category("UserPanel"),
    System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(null)]
    public string UserName
    {
        get 
        { 
            return userName; 
        }
        set
        {
            userName = value;
        }
    }
    [System.ComponentModel.Description("Password for DB Connection"),
    System.ComponentModel.Category("UserPanel"),
    System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(null)]
    public string UserPassWord
    {
        get
        {
            return userPassWord;
        }
        set
        {
            userPassWord = value;
        }
    }

    public MyComponent()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        userName = "username";
        userPassWord = "pass";
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Draw(e.Graphics); 
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
    protected virtual void Draw(Graphics g)
    {
        DrawButton(g);
    }

    protected virtual void DrawButton(Graphics g)
    {
        Rectangle rcButton = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);
        ControlPaint.DrawButton(g, rcButton, state );
    }

   public void MyFunction()
    { 
     // What my components do.
     string appname =System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;
    }
```

I try to learn project name with this code "System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;" but it gives me "MyComponenet". I want it gives me "TestProject"
Now what i need to do ? I think i need a function like this

```
protected override void afterComponenetsCreatedOnForm() 
    {
        base.afterComponenetsCreatedOnForm();
        MyFunction();
    }
```

Comment: Its so important for me, I hope somebody come and try to help me

Comment: I did used "Application.ProductName;" instead of "System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;" but now it gives me "Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2012", but if  i use this code in any form application, it gives me MyProjectName

Comment: `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name` always gives you the name of the assembly in which this code is currently run. So most likely you are calling it in the wrong location. 
But due to a lack of understanding on my side what you actually want to achieve a little bit of explanation has to be done from your side please

Comment: thanks for your answer @ManuelZelenka . I did embed some project in my database. I know InitLayout, Update, Refresh functions means. But i need to learn how can i find my component is runnig which form ? My component will update on database  if my projects version (which my componenet is runnig on) under database project version. firstly my component need to learn where its runnig? i hope you can understand me. I am sorry for my language :(

Comment: so i need to learn which part of component life cycle i can find where my component  is runnig (which project?) ? it means, i need component life cycle part like after created on a form @ManuelZelenka